# How to to ignore dev dependencies when loading linked packages in a monorepo?

Tags: node.js, webpack, dependencies, node-modules, monorepo

We have a repository containing plugins for a JavaScript library—let's call it "`lib`"—that is not part of this repo.  This repo organised as a monorepo using [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna).   All the plugins are (like `lib` itself) published as NPM packages, and each of the plugins has `lib` as both a peer dependency and dev dependency; additionally, some of the plugins hav other plugins as a (regular) dependency.

After running `lenra bootstrap`, the repository looks like (simplified):

```
plugins/
├─┬ a/
│ ├── index.js
│ └─┬ node_modules/
│   ├─┬ lib/
│   │ └── (... contents elided)
│   └─┬ @lib/
│     └── b@ -> ../../../b
└─┬ b/
  ├── index.js
  └─┬ node_modules/
    └─┬ lib/
      └── (... contents elided)
```

Note that plugins which depend on each other are symlinked by Lerna, and each gets its own copy of `lib` because it is a dev dependency.

`plugins/a/index.js` includes:

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
import * as b from 'b';
```

`plugins/b/index.js` includes only:

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
```

Unfortunately, `lib` maintains some internal state, and loading `plugins/a/index.js` results `a` and `b` getting the two separate copies of `lib` causing tests that depend on `a` and `b` seeing the same internal state to fail.

Since `lib` is a peer dependency of the `@lib/a` and `@lib/b` packages this will not affect users of the NPM packages, since they will (under normal circumstances) be installed beside a single copy of `lib`.  The trouble only arises because `lib` is also installed as a dev dependency of `b`, and that copy is preferred.

**Is there a way to prevent `b` from loading the copy of `lib` installed as a dev dependency, when it is itself being loaded as a dependency of `a`, but to use `a`'s copy instead?**

This issue has come to light because we have been using webpack to build separate bundles for each test suite, and our `webpack.config.js` has until now contained the directive:

```
{
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      lib: path.resolve(fs.realpathSync(process.cwd()), 'node_modules/lib'),
    },
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

which has the effect of causing all attempts to import `lib` to import the copy from the top-level plugin (in this case `plugins/a/node_modules/lib`).

Unfortunately, using `resolve.alias` in this way has at least two shortcomings:

- First and most pressingly, it seems to cause webpack to ignore the recently-added `exports` clause in `lib`'s `package.json` file, resulting in import errors (particularly for subpath exports).  I tried `alias: {lib: 'lib'}`, in the hope that it might force use of a single copy of `lib` without ignoring the rest of usual node module resolution rules, but alas it did not.
- It makes us dependent on bundling the code + tests before running the tests, which is significantly slower than just running the tests directly in node.js.

Comment: instead of using `lerna bootstrap` (which was deprecated), I now always go with pnpm [`workspace:`](https://pnpm.io/workspaces#workspace-protocol-workspace) protocol (both pnpm & yarn are supporting it). This protocol is using symlinks referencing each package dist from your package.json `main` or `exports` (in other words it acts as if you were using them from npm but in fact they use the local version via symlinks), npm also has workspaces but they don't support the `workspace:` protocol yet. Also both Lerna and Lerna-Lite supports `workspace:` protocol

Comment: I attempted to solve this problem by removing `lib` as a dev dependency of `a` and `b`, and instead adding it as a dev dependency at the top level of the repository.  However, it seems that npm installs peer dependencies even if they are not dev dependencies.  In the process of trying to see if this behaviour could be disabled I discovered https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5080 which suggests we are using peer dependencies incorrectly (but does not provide any clear alternative I can fully comprehend).  (@ghiscoding: note that the the same problem occurs with `npm link` as with Lerna.)